# How do I programmatically add items to a Horizontal List at runtime?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I've been searching for a Horizontal List View. I haven't found one. But I did find the Grid View (which displays images horizontally) on the Google Android website. [see [bottom](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html) of this page for screenshot].

The problem is, I'm not using Java. I'm using C#/Monodroid/Xamarin Studio.

And I'm not using Images. I need to display proper list items (say for example, some kind of panel or div-like thing which contains a little header and a description beneath it for each list item), and display all these List Items horizontally in the GridView.

I have no idea which Adapter I should use. I think I should use the ArrayAdapter for this, simply because it's the only Adapter I've seen that seems to match what I want to do.

Also, 99% of the tutorials online that I've found don't really explain how to dynamically add items to a horizontal list view/grid view at runtime either. They all seem to use static string arrays/xml files as the source of their data items.

So my question is, how do I create a horizontally-scrolling List (whether that be a GridView or something else) and programmatically add items to it at runtime?

If I'm not describing this clearly, here's how it should be:

[image: Horizontal List Item Demonstration]

Comment: When building UIs with Xamarin, you shouldn't be afraid to look for some java/objective-C answers and convert the code to C# yourself. These are basic android UI questions, I would suggest you to search for them separately, there are already quite a lot of answers that explain them better than I would (search for "Android horizontal GridView", "Android custom list adapters", "Add items to an adapter at runtime")

Comment: @Dalmas thanks for the advice. I'm not afraid. This is actually my second app for android and last night I wrote a Floating Action Button for Android L in c# just by looking at some Java code. However there are some things that still confuse me since I come from a Windows dev background and android seems a bit weird still since I'm so new to it. I did try writing it myself for the horizontal list but I just don't get the existing tutorials so I couldn't translate it to c# anyway

Comment: i might be off topic, but in `Java` (Android) you would call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter object once you've modified the data in that adapter. After that, `ListView` will update its contents

Comment: @LongiLong are there any simple examples you can point me to for dynamically adding items at runtime? Even if it's in Java that's still be good. The tutorials I've come across are very focused on different cases and pages and pages long.

Comment: Can you create a view and add it to your list? I'm trying to do something similar. I'm using VS for Mac Xamran to a Mac app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586420/how-to-add-a-custom-view-dynamically-to-a-view-in-visual-studio-for-mac-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

[Check the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)) for `ArrayAdapter`, especially methods like `addAll` or `insert(Object,index)`

Your `HorizontalListView` has one (in your case) `ArrayAdapter` with one datasource. To change your data you

1. Change your datasource in the `Adapter`
2. The `Adapter` has to notify the `ListView` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` (you have to call notifyDataSetChanged yourself! Otherwise, the ListView will not update its content)
3. `ListView` will update it's content

Inside your `Adapter`:

```
Array<YourObject> dataSource;

//...

//Either override existing method
@Override
public void add(YourObject newItem) {
    dataSource.add(newItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//write an own one
public void updatedata(Array<YourObject> newItems){
    //add your custom logic by manipulating the dataSource array yourself

    //for example: change everything
    self.dataSource = newItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this at your ArrayAdapter

```
myAdapter.updatedata(Array<YourObject>)
```

or get Adapter from your ListView if you don't have a reference with

```
((YourCustomArrayAdapter)yourListView.getAdapter).updatedata(Array<YourObject>)
```

And just for the record, if your adapter should be wrapped, do this crazy shit..This took me some time.

```
(
    (
        YourCustomArrayAdapter (HeaderViewListAdapter)yourListView.getAdapter()
    ).getWrappedAdapter()
).updatedata(Array<YourObject>);
```

Hope it helps..Took some time till I understood my code. I was in a really freaky good mood that time :D

Comment: Thanks so much longilong lol! Where you put YourObject newItem do you mean something like a view in an xml file like a relative layout with some elements like text in it?

Comment: YourObject is your DataModel (String headline = "List Item #1" String content = "Llorem ipsum...") which will be generated in your Adapter `getView()`... Maybe this tutorial might be helpful: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Do lists support custom views or something like Item Renderers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586420/how-to-add-a-custom-view-dynamically-to-a-view-in-visual-studio-for-mac-c-sharp

Comment: @1.21gigawatts i would n use (Horizontal)ListView anymore. Use `RecyclerView`

Comment: @longi use a recycler? are you saying my code is trash? ...that’s fair... /j

Comment: @1.21gigawatts :-D sorry, i thought this was an Android question. My answer doesn't count for Xamarin C# ;-) good luck bro!